# Will Exporting Meshes in Three.js Improve Performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

So I am working on a Three.js project and the program seems to lag in some places. Specifically, the most performance lag occurs when rendering the text Meshes I have created like so:

```
var text1Geo = new THREE.TextGeometry("Hello", {font: font});
text1Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(text1Geo, textMaterial);
text1Mesh.position.set(-6500, 150, -500);
text1Mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(text1Mesh);
```

I am wondering if it would improve performance if I exported the text as an obj using the OBJExporter and then instead of creating a THREE.TextGeometry I could just load the mesh into the scene using an OBJLoader. Would this improve the performance. If you would like to see the entire project and source code please go [here](http://pixelpusher.ninja/Ocean%20World/new%201.html). Any other tips or advice on how to improve performance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any difference in performance if to remove `text1Mesh.castShadow = true;` ?

Comment: I expect you can answer your question yourself by doing an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

No.

An experiment is still in order, but the answer is to **cache** the text geometry.

Instead of having something like

```js
loadText( 'url.obj' , (t)=>{ /*...do stuff...*/});
```

you can have

```js
computeText(){ 
  var t = new THREE.TextGeometry();
  ...
}

computeText();
//...do stuff...
```

My assumption is that obj is unfriendly when it comes to parsing, but i might be wrong. A formatted json would perhaps be better, or binary.

So, instead of downloading an .obj, parsing it, indexing, and then doing something, just compute it before you start rendering.

You'd most likely experience lag nonetheless when this thing hits the gpu, be it computed or downloaded.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback! Loading the text as an obj actually did help the fps but only very very slightly. What I did was load the object before rendering and stored it in a variable like text1Mesh. Isn't this technically considered caching the obj? I will next see if there is any improvement if I use a json or binary format instead of obj.

Comment: Text can be 2D, so use transparent plane with texture (texture is your text .png)

Comment: two things can cause your fps to drop, something taking a while to compute on the cpu, or something taking a while to upload to the gpu. The upload happens the first time you call `renderer.render()` and it encounters that object. Try doing renderer.render() after you load your text (in any way), and then starting your actual render loop, there wont be any stutters. But this is kind of a different question. I can update my response to elaborate more on what's going on but i think we should rephrase the question?